Is there a way to force VSCode copilot /doc to use Numpy format?
I know that you can do inline chat "/doc numpy format" but it would be nice to not have to add the additional instructions every time.
I just tried the new experimental github.copilot.chat.experimental.codeGeneration.instructions
with
"github.copilot.chat.experimental.codeGeneration.instructions": [
    {
        "text": "always use Numpy-format docstrings for Python code."
    },
    {
        "text": "always generate docstrings with full parameter and return value descriptions."
    }
]

but it made no difference (I guess, strictly speaking, this isn't code generation, so may not have any effect on docstring generation).

Hello, if not the code. There is currently no way to directly force Github Copilot to generate the specified document characters. You can use """ to start a new document character and then type Parameters, Returns, Examples etc.
